# Java: Print specific substring based on characters appearing before, and end if meeting letters after?

Tags: java, string, substring

I have an input string, let's say it's `111.112.111.0.0 > 111.33.44.55.11 pxs ikf len 3348` , it might also sometimes be input via the stream as `111.112.111.0.0 > 111.33.44.55.11 pxs ikf len 3348 BBBTTT`.

How do I capture the numbers occuring after "len" in the via substring? Using `system.out.println(stringStr.substring(stringStr.lastIndexOf(" ") + 1)` will only print `3348` if it's the last part of the string above, but if BBBTTT appears, it will not work.

How do I print the numbers of a substring specifically after "len" but not including anything but the numbers that follow(might be 0-9999, not more), so not any characters following?

Comment: This is a candidate for RegularExpressions. Learn about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `split` method for this.

```
        String s = "111.112.111.0.0 > 111.33.44.55.11 pxs ikf len 3348 BBBTTT";
    s = s.split("len")[1];
    s = s.replaceAll("\\D+", "");
    System.out.println(s);
```

or just

```
s = s.split("len")[1].replaceAll("\\D+", "");
```

Comment: I didnt express myself clearly. I want only the 1-4 digits, not including BBBTTT

Comment: still not good if you have `111.112.111.0.0 > 111.33.44.55.11 pxs ikf len 3348 BBBTT18T`, you will get `334818` instead of `3348`

Comment: then use split again s = s.split("len")[1]; and s = s.split(" ")[1]; will split from the next whitespace

Answer (score 3):

Use RegEx. The pattern would be something like "len ([\d]+)"

```
String inputString = "111.112.111.0.0 > 111.33.44.55.11 pxs ikf len 3348 BBBTTT";
String regEx = "len ([\\d]+)";
String regExMatch = "";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regEx);
Matcher m = p.matcher(inputString);
if (m.find()) {
    regExMatch = m.group(1); // save the first capture group
}
System.out.println(regExMatch);
```

Comment: Can't I use this directly in the system.out.println line? regex that is

Comment: @cbll you could either store it to a variable or create a separate function and have it return just the string. If you HAD to, I guess you could put it all in a single line, but it's not good practice to do so and it would be difficult to read.

Answer (score 1):

You could be using regular expressions here, but there are other ways:

1. Determine the index of "len" in your string
2. Add 4 to that - that is where your number starts
3. Do a substring from there

That string will either contain "just digigits"; or digits followed by a space. So you can do another indexOf() call to figure if there is a space; and if so, throw away everything after that space, too; like:

```
String numberWithChars = "3348 BBBTTT";
int indexOfSpace = numberWithChars.indexOf(" ");
if  (indexOfSpace > 0) {
   String pureNumber = numberWithChars.substring(0, indexOfSpace);
} else {
   String pureNumber = numberWithChars;
}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Example with your two strings using a regex :

```
        String s1 = "111.112.111.0.0 > 111.33.44.55.11 pxs ikf len 3348";
        String s2 = "111.112.111.0.0 > 111.33.44.55.11 pxs ikf len 3349 BBBTTT";

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*len (\\d*).*");
        Matcher m1 = pattern.matcher(s1);
        Matcher m2 = pattern.matcher(s2);
        if (m1.matches()) {
            System.out.println(m1.group(1));
        }
        if (m2.matches()) {
            System.out.println(m2.group(1));
        }
```

You could put this in a separate method :

```
public class ExtractLen {
private static final Pattern LEN_PATTERN = Pattern.compile(".*len (\\d*).*");

public String extractLen(String s) {
    Matcher m1 = LEN_PATTERN.matcher(s);
    if (m1.matches()) {
        return m1.group(1);
    }
    return null;
}}
```

Comment: Can't I implement it directly in the system.out.println as a condition, like the substring?

Comment: @cbll You could extract it to a class with method like the updated answer

Answer (score 1):

You may use a `replaceFirst` with a not-so-simple regex:

```
.*\blen\s+(\d+).*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TcaHaB/1)

**Details**:

- `.*` - any 0+ chars other than linebreak symbols, as many as possible
- `\blen` - a whole word `len` (`\b` is a word boundary)
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `(\d+)` - Group 1 capturing 1+ digits
- `.*` - any 0+ chars other than linebreak symbols.

The `$1` is a backereference to the contents captured into Group 1.

If your string can contain linebreaks, add `(?s)` at the start of the regex.

See [Java demo](http://ideone.com/raXf29):

```
String s  = "111.112.111.0.0 > 111.33.44.55.11 pxs ikf len 3348";
System.out.println(s.replaceFirst(".*\\blen\\s+(\\d+).*", "$1"));
```